# Some of the records are not inserted into database tables

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

We're running Selenium tests, which are around 1100, on three machines simultaneously. On each machine, those tests run in 7 threads i.e. on each machine, 7 tests run in parallel.

After EACH test execution is completed, we insert record in database table with details of the test and its status like Passed, Failed, Skipped.

When tests are run on single machine with 7 threads, records are correctly added in table, but when tests are run on all three machines, each with 7 threads, then for some of the tests, record is not inserted.

Database server we're using is `Oracle 11.2.0`

I'm not getting how to find root cause of this. Could you please help with the same?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about it but I think what happened is when you're using threads of the same machine, you're also using the same connection to the DB so they can't collide, but when using different hosts as well you need to lock the use of the DB or table for that specific connection.

If you could add more about the back-end framework you're using to query the DB I'll try and be more helpful.